# In the initial load of my page my SelectedPerson object is not getting set after the Dropdown is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a sample Angular page that is not setting my bound SelectedPerson variable on the startup.

The page load, loads a drop down and selects the 3rd item (X3) correctly, but the bound var {SelectedPerson} is not getting set. It works when I manually select an item.

Here is my code. You can run the test at..
https://stackblitz.com/edit/personselector1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" name="PersonSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPersonChange($event)"
        [(ngModel)]="SelectedPerson" [compareWith]="byPersonId">
        <option *ngFor="let r of lstPerson" [ngValue]="r">{{r.PersonNumber}} - {{r.PersonName}}</option>
    </select>

  <br><br>

  <label>Person ID: {{SelectedPerson.PersonNumber}}</label><br>
  <label>Person Number: {{SelectedPerson.PersonNumber}}</label><br>
  <label>Person Name: {{SelectedPerson.PersonNumber}}</label><br>

  <br>

    <button  (click)="GetSelected()">Get Selected</button>  
   <label>  Person Name: {{mySelectedMessage}}</label><br>

</div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonInfo } from './PersonInfo';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  
{
  //
  //    Globals
  //  
  mySelectedMessage: any = 'Nothing'

  lstPerson: any = [];

  SelectedPerson: PersonInfo = 
  {
    PersonID: null,
    PersonNumber: null,
    PersonName: null
  } 

  //
  //    Init
  //
  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.LoadPersonList();
  } 

  //
  //    Display Selected Person
  //
  GetSelected()
  {
    this.mySelectedMessage = this.SelectedPerson.PersonName;
    console.log('SelectedPerson', this.SelectedPerson)
  }
    
  //
  //    Load Dropdown
  //
  LoadPersonList() 
  {
    var temp = [
        { PersonID: 1, PersonNumber: 'X1', PersonName: 'Dave Smith' },
        { PersonID: 2, PersonNumber: 'X2', PersonName: 'Tammy Spoon' },
        { PersonID: 3, PersonNumber: 'X3', PersonName: 'Rosy Cheeks' },
        { PersonID: 4, PersonNumber: 'X4', PersonName: 'Don Key' },
    ];    

    this.lstPerson = temp;

    if (this.lstPerson.length > 1) 
    {
      this.lstPerson.unshift(
      {
        PersonID: 0,
        PersonNumber: "- Select a Person",
        PersonName: ""
      })
      } 
      else 
      {
      this.SelectedPerson = this.lstPerson[0];
      }         

  }

  //
  //    byPersonId - For [compareWith] in .html
  //
  byPersonId(item1: any, item2: any) 
  {
    return item1.PersonID === 3;
  }

  //
  //    onPersonChange - Person Selector Change
  //
    onPersonChange(value) 
    {
    //this.mySelectedMessage = value.PersonName;
    console.log("Person Change: ", value);
    }  
}
```

**PersonInfo**

```
export interface PersonInfo
{
    PersonID: number,
    PersonNumber: string,
    PersonName: string
}
```

Comment: Edit: In the sample code I have

  byPersonId(item1: any, item2: any) 
  {
    return item1.PersonID === 3;
  }

I intend to replace the 3 with a variable. So I need this to work without hard coding any solution that would set the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Working code is here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/personselectorv2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

If I Understand the problem properly. in `LoadPersonList` function `this.SelectedPerson = this.lstPerson[0];` will not execute. remove the else block that wrapped this piece of function may solve your problem.

Comment: @Mike try to bring this.SelectedPerson = this.lstPerson[0] before if statement

Comment: Nope, SelectedPerson does get assigned, but to element[0]. The dropdown has the personid 3 selected. I want it to load with person 3 selected and SelectedPerson set to personid 3.

Comment: If you goto https://stackblitz.com/edit/personselector1?file=src/app/app.component.ts and try it you will see.

Comment: checkout this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/personselector1-hezuj8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I see what you suggested. adding this.SelectedPerson = this.lstPerson[2]; will not work for me. It works in this example but... I should have been more clear on my intentions. The sample I supplied was a simplified version if my production code. I just wanted to make a simple example to post. What my end goal is to have the value in the byPersonId function a variable (return item1.PersonID === intSomeVar;). So not knowing the index, your solution will now work me.

Comment: Correction: to my last statement, "your solution will not work for me."